# Shiny with DT Select rows, keep cell color

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a DT datatable that has cells colored according to a different variable. When you click on a row, it highlights values in a corresponding plot, exactly like in the example [here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-rows/). However, when you select a row, the new color that highlights the row overrides my existing colors. I'd like for the row to be highlighted, but the individual cell to maintain its color if it was already colored.

The screenshots below show what I'm getting and what I want. I modified Yihui's code to make a reproducible example below the screenshots. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Colored cells]

[image: Color overridden]

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  title = 'Select Table Rows',

  fluidRow(
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('x1')),
    column(6, plotOutput('x2', height = 500))
  )


)

server <- function(input, output) {
  cars <- cars %>% 
    mutate(low_speed = ifelse(speed < 5, 1, 0))

  output$x1 <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(cars,
              options = list(columnDefs = list(list(targets = 3,
                                                    visible = FALSE)))) %>% 
      formatStyle("speed", "low_speed",
                  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), 
                                             c("transparent", "#E34755")))
  })

  # highlight selected rows in the scatterplot
  output$x2 <- renderPlot({
    s <- input$x1_rows_selected
    par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, .1))
    plot(cars[ ,-3])
    if (length(s)) points(cars[s, , drop = FALSE], pch = 19, cex = 2)
  })



}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a CSS class for the background color (`red` below) and add it to the desired cells with a `rowCallback`. Then add this CSS:

```
.red {
  background-color: #e34755;
}
table.dataTable tr.selected td.red {
  background-color: #e34755 !important;
}
```

The app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

rowCallback <- c(
  "function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if(dat[1] < 5){",
  "    $('td:eq(1)', row).addClass('red');",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

css <- "
.red {
  background-color: #e34755;
}
table.dataTable tr.selected td.red {
  background-color: #e34755 !important;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),

  title = 'Select Table Rows',

  fluidRow(
    column(6, DTOutput('x1')),
    column(6, plotOutput('x2', height = 500))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$x1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(cars,
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(list(targets = 3,visible = FALSE)),
                rowCallback = JS(rowCallback)
              )
    )
  })

  # highlight selected rows in the scatterplot
  output$x2 <- renderPlot({
    s <- input$x1_rows_selected
    par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, .1))
    plot(cars[ ,-3])
    if (length(s)) points(cars[s, , drop = FALSE], pch = 19, cex = 2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can make this happen with some custom CSS. Add this code block to your `fluidPage`:

```
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML(
      "table.dataTable tbody tr.selected td {
       color: white !important;
       background-color: #E34755 !important;}"
      )
      )
  ),
```

You could also drop that CSS snippet into a standalone file and place it in the `www` directory alongside your app file(s). See here for more [Shiny CSS info](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).

[Live Demo](https://nathanday.shinyapps.io/demo/)

Comment: So this is super helpful, but not *quite* what I was after. In my specific application, it's pretty important that the user can see which cells are colored. So I'd ideally like the individual cell color to stay what it is while the rest of the row is highlighted in the blue-ish color it is by default.

Comment: its probably better to have a table specific highlight, above will change color for all tables