# Change cell color after updated value, not overwritten by selection

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

Basically what I want is a combination of these two answered posts

[Change backgorund color of cell of data table while its value is edited in Rshiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949053/change-backgorund-color-of-cell-of-data-table-while-its-value-is-edited-in-rshin)

[Shiny with DT Select rows, keep cell color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051650/shiny-with-dt-select-rows-keep-cell-color)

so I want the cell color to change after each edit on the client side, but when the rows  with an edited cell are selected, I need the selection highlight **to not** overwrite the cell colorization, (so that it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2Gjv.png).

Difference between my problem and the one here
[Shiny with DT Select rows, keep cell color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051650/shiny-with-dt-select-rows-keep-cell-color)
is that in my case the cell colors which need to keep their cell colors can not be hardocoded as they are selected by the client.

code which enables the cell colorization after cell edit (code from @StéphaneLaurent (I only changed a minor thing so  that now selections are possible)), however here the selection "overwrites" the yellow cells. Is it even possible to achieve what I want?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

js <- HTML(
  "function colorizeCell(i, j){
    var selector = '#dtable tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:nth-child(' + j + ')';
    $(selector).css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
  }"
)

colorizeCell <- function(i, j){
  sprintf("colorizeCell(%d, %d)", i, j)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$script(js)
  ),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

dat <- iris[1:5, ]

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, editable = TRUE)
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["dtable_cell_edit"]]
    i <- info[["row"]]
    j <- info[["col"]]
    runjs(colorizeCell(i, j+1))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

css <- HTML(
  "table.dataTable tr.selected td.yellow {
     background-color: yellow !important
   }
   td.yellow {
     background-color: yellow !important
   }"
)

js <- HTML(
  "function colorizeCell(i, j){
    var selector = '#dtable tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:nth-child(' + j + ')';
    $(selector).addClass('yellow');
  }"
)

colorizeCell <- function(i, j){
  sprintf("colorizeCell(%d, %d)", i, j)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(css),
    tags$script(js)
  ),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

dat <- iris[1:5, ]

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, editable = TRUE)
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["dtable_cell_edit"]]
    i <- info[["row"]]
    j <- info[["col"]]
    runjs(colorizeCell(i, j+1))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Parfait, merci beaucoup! :)