# Customising the colour and transparency of a selected row in conditionally-formatted DT::datatable in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt, bslib

I need to display a table in a Shiny app with the following requirements:

- app uses bslib themes (important because [changes the css needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76219061/5171028))
- table has conditional formatting (colours representing numeric values)
- the ability to select one or more rows in table
- when a row is selected, you can *still see* the conditional formatting

The default settings for datatable do not enable the last point - when you select a row, the selection colour is opaque and on top of the conditional formatting.

In contrast, a package like rhandsontable takes an excel-like approach where the selected row is indicated with a semi-transparent colour.

I can't use rhandsontable for other reasons, and I also cannot use the formattable package, because it (at present) converts numeric values into strings which prevents sorting the table by header correctly (see the [github issue](https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable/issues/92)). So I am using DT's built-in conditional formatting functions (formatStyle, styleInterval).

Here's a minimal app that meets all the requirements, but there's something weird going on with the colour of the row selection and I'd like to understand it.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- bslib::page_fluid(
  theme = bslib::bs_add_rules(
    bslib::bs_theme(),
    sass::as_sass("table.dataTable tbody tr.active td {
             color: black !important;
             box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2) !important;}"
    )),
  DT::dataTableOutput("test_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  iris_small = iris %>% dplyr::slice_sample(n = 10)

  output$test_table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    cols_to_format <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")

    # create 19 breaks and 20 rgb color values ranging from white to red
    brks <- quantile(iris_small[cols_to_format], probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
    clrs <- round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(brks) + 1), 0) %>%
      {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}

    iris_dt <- DT::datatable(
      iris_small,
      selection = 'multiple',
      class = "hover row-border order-column compact nowrap",
    )

    iris_dt <- iris_dt %>%
      DT::formatStyle(
        cols_to_format,
        target = "cell",
        backgroundColor = DT::styleInterval(brks, clrs)
      )

    iris_dt
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server = server)
```

I have chosen to conditionally format the cells from white to red based on their value (guided by [this example](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html)).

To change the colour of the selected row, I have used a bit of css guided by the kind person who  [answered a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76014293/5171028). Here, I have modified the css to use the rgba() function add transparency so the conditional formatting can still be seen.

For the conditionally-formatted columns this works well.

**But for the row numbers, and any columns that are not formatted, the transparent yellow colour indicating a row selection appears to overlap a blue colour.**

[image]

I am not sure how to figure out where this blue colour comes from, and how to remove it. I can see that [box-shadow](https://datatables.net/blog/2022-05-13#Row-colouring-improvements) is the property to set the colour of the selected row. I also tried adjusting the `background-color` property, this doesn't work (doesn't go transparent). I am fairly new to css and I don't know how to find what other property might be causing this blue colour to appear.

I can work around this (by turning off row names and by setting all cells to a white background with formatStyle before applying the conditional formatting), but I wanted to ask this question here because:

1. I'd like to understand why it's happening and how to fix it, and also
2. although there are related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051650/shiny-with-dt-select-rows-keep-cell-color) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73128949/change-cell-color-after-updated-value-not-overwritten-by-selection?noredirect=1&lq=1), I have not seen an example available showing how to create a transparent row selection for a conditionally-formatted DT table, and I thought it might be a useful reference

Comment: i have to replace `tr.active` with `tr.selected` in your code, otherwise a selected row is entirely blue. And the result is fine with `tr.selected`. What are the versions of your packages,

Comment: Ah! Interesting. I was using DT v0.27. On that version, switching to tr.selected did not work, but when I upgraded to v0.30, I got the behaviour you describe. Thank you! If you would like to add this as an answer I'll accept it. (And for reference, the other relevant package versions were shiny 1.7.4 and bslib 0.4.2).